# TCS MockVita 2019 Round 2 Question: Hop Game

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem asked in TCS MockVita 2019 Round 2:

Problem Description

Dr Felix Kline, the Math teacher at Gauss School introduced the following game to teach his students problem solving. He places a series of “hopping stones” (pieces of paper) in a line with points (a positive number) marked on each of the stones.

Students start from one end and hop to the other end. One can step on a stone and add the number on the stone to their cumulative score or jump over a stone and land on the next stone. In this case, they get twice the points marked on the stone they land but do not get the points marked on the stone they jumped over.

At most once in the journey, the student is allowed (if they choose) to do a “double jump”– that is, they jump over two consecutive stones – where they would get three times the points of the stone they land on, but not the points of the stone they jump over.

The teacher expected his students to do some thinking and come up with a plan to get the maximum score possible. Given the numbers on the sequence of stones, write a program to determine the maximum score possible.

Constraints

The number of stones in the sequence< 30

Input Format

The first line contains N, the number of integers (this is a positive integer)

The next line contains the N points (each a positive integer) separated by commas. These are the points on the stones in the order the stones are placed.

Output

One integer representing the maximum score

Test Case

Explanation

Example 1

Input

3

4,2,3

Output

10

Explanation

There are 3 stones (N=3), and the points (in the order laid out) are 4,2 and 3 respectively.

If we step on the first stone and skip the second to get 4 + 2 x 3 = 10. A double jump to the third stone will get only 9. Hence the result is 10, and the double jump is not used

Example 2

Input

6

4,5,6,7,4,5

Output

35

Explanation

N=6, and the sequence of points is given.One way of getting 35 is to start with a double jump to stone 3 (3 x 6=18), go to stone 4 (7) and jump to stone 6 (10 points) for a total of 35. The double jump was used only once, and the result is 35.

I found that it's a Dynamic programming problem, but I don't know what I did wrong because my solution is not able to pass all the test cases. My code passed all the tests I created.

```cpp
unordered_map<int, int> lookup;
int res(int *arr, int n, int i){

    if(i == n-1){
        return 0;
    }

    if(i == n-2){
        return arr[i+1];
    }

    if(lookup.find(i) != lookup.end())
        return lookup[i];

    int maxScore = 0;

    if(i< n-3 && flag == false){
        flag = true;
        maxScore = max(maxScore, 3 * (arr[i+3]) + res(arr, n, i+3));
        flag = false;
    }
    maxScore = max(maxScore, (arr[i+1] + res(arr,n,i+1)));

    lookup[i] = max(maxScore, 2 * (arr[i+2]) + res(arr, n, i+2));

    return lookup[i];
}

cout << res(arr, n, 0) + arr[0];  // It is inside the main()
```

I expect you to find the mistake in my code and give the correct solution, and any test case which fails this solution. Thanks :)

Comment: You should try to make your solution non-recursive. Also, explaining your solution and using descriptive variable names would make the code easier to understand.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez please see the note I left on the [list of revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56637078/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any map. All you need to remember are last few maximal values. You have two options every move (except two first), end with double jump made or without it. If you don't want ot make a dj then your best joice is maximum of last stone + current and stone before last + 2 * current `max(no_dj[2] + arr[i], no_dj[1] + 2 * arr[i])`.

On the other hand, if you want to have dj made than you have three options, either jump one stone after some previous dj `dj[2] + arr[i]` or jump over last stone after some dj `dj[1] + 2 * arr[i]` or do double jump in current move `no_dj[0] + 3 * arr[i]`.

```
int res(int *arr, int n){
    int no_dj[3]{ 0, 0, arr[0]};
    int dj[3]{ 0, 0, 0};

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        int best_nodj = max(no_dj[1] + 2 * arr[i], no_dj[2] + arr[i]);
        int best_dj = 0;
        if(i > 1) best_dj = max(max(dj[1] + 2 * arr[i], dj[2] + arr[i]), no_dj[0] + 3 * arr[i]);

        no_dj[0] = no_dj[1];
        no_dj[1] = no_dj[2];
        no_dj[2] = best_nodj;
        dj[0] = dj[1];
        dj[1] = dj[2];
        dj[2] = best_dj;
    }
    return max(no_dj[2], dj[2]);
}
```

All you have to remember are two arrays of three elements. Last three maximum values after double jump and last three maximum values without double jump.